# Mobile phone SDK's Linux binaries

Tags: java, linux, java-me, mobile, sdk

On various mobile phone developer sites like Nokia, Sony Ericsson, Motorola etc...
I found Java ME development SDK's for mobile phones but only installable on Windows OS...      I have a Ubuntu OS (Jaunty Jackelope) at home and was wondering if Mobile SDK's Linux installable versions are available?..
I have the NetBeans IDE installed on Ubuntu...

Answer (score 1):

You can always give windows a try on a VM if you are keen and the sdk is restrictive.

Answer (score 1):

[WTK](http://java.sun.com/products/sjwtoolkit/download-2_2.html) can be installed in Linux. This is a general SDK and it lacks manufacturer's specific libraries. However it will be OK for most of your applications.

Comment: Well I have the WTK already preinstalled with NetBeans I was looking at manufacturer specific SDKs...

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a windows VM or wine you should be able to install the handset maker dev kit, extract their API jars (and documentation maybe?) then discard the rest of the kit.

Done this with many APIs.